# How to pass Datetime externally into SQL

Tags: linq

How to write code for getting that record By passing Date,MM,Year,HH,MM,SS
all these parameters are coming from DropdownList

```
public JsonResult Dif(int Day = 0, int Month=0, int Year=0, int HH, int MM, int Ss)
{
    var x = (from n in db.Employees
             where n.DataofBirth = (Day,Month,Year)
             select n).First();
    return new JsonResult { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `DateTime`:

```
var date = new DateTime(Year, Month, Day, HH, MM, Ss);
var x = (from n in db.Employees
         where n.DataofBirth = date
         select n).First();
```

Also, it doesn't really make sense for the parameters to have a default value... especially if it's not a valid value! Neither the year, month or day can be 0.